# Como adicionar vários itens no $paymentRequest->addItem?

Tags: php

Bom, eu adicionei 1 item ao checkout do Pagseguro mas gostaria de inserir vários itens. Como posso inserir vários itens passando estes itens em **$data**?

```
public function pagar(){

    // Pega os itens enviados para o método produtos + adiciona os itens ao checkout do Pagseguro
    $items = self::produtos();
    $produtos = new PagSeguroItem($items);
    $paymentRequest->addItem($produtos);
...
}

public static function produtos()
{
    $data = array(       
        'id'            => '0001', 
        'description'   => 'Notebook Dell', 
        'quantity'      => 2, 
        'amount'        => 2150.00
    );
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você não consegue adicionar o paymentRequest em uma variável e depois incrementa-la?

Utilizando o moip tive uma situação parecida e resolvi da seguinte forma:

```
 $order = $moip->orders()->setOwnId(uniqid())->setCustomerId($idcliente_moip);
      for($x=0; $x < count($produtos); $x++){
           $order->addItem($produtos[$x], 1, $produtos[$x], $totalEmCentavos);
      }

 $order->create();
```

Vale Ressaltar que nesse caso $produtos é um array com os produtos da lista.

Como nunca utilizei o pagseguro, não tenho certeza se dessa forma funciona, no entanto vale a tentativa.

Answer (score 0):

A única forma que vejo é tendo uma classe para o Pag Seguro, pois cada item deve ter seu `addItem`.

Vou exemplificar com uma classe genérica, sem ser a do Pag Seguro:

```
<?php

class Pagseguro
{
    private $itens = array();

    public function addItem(PagSeguroItem $item)
    {
        array_push($this->itens, $item);
    }

    public function make()
    {
        foreach($this->itens as $item) {
            //Aqui iria o real add item
            echo $item->nome . " | " . $item->preco . "<br>";
        }

    }

}

class PagSeguroItem
{
    public $nome, $preco;

    public function __construct($nome, $preco) 
    {
        $this->nome = $nome;
        $this->preco = $preco;
    }
}

$ps = new PagSeguro();

$ps->addItem(new PagSeguroItem('Notebook', 1800.80));
$ps->addItem(new PagSeguroItem('Mouse sem fio', 50.80));
$ps->addItem(new PagSeguroItem('Case notebook', 100.80));

$ps->make();
```

A saída seria:

```
Notebook | 1800.8
Mouse sem fio | 50.8
Case notebook | 100.8
```

Assim, no `foreach` de `make()`, você poderia chamar o `$paymentRequest->addItem($item->id, $item->nome, $item->quantidade, $item->preco);`, pois segundo a [documentação da API](https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/guia-de-integracao/documentacao-da-biblioteca-pagseguro-em-php.html#!rmcl), o `addItem` seria assim:

```
$paymentRequest = new PagSeguroPaymentRequest();  
$paymentRequest->addItem('0001', 'Notebook', 1, 2430.00);  
$paymentRequest->addItem('0002', 'Mochila',  1, 150.99);
```